# Geometry nodes delete points to close to specific point

Tags: geometry, nodes

Long story short i have a problem with my circles packing algorithm. It works with circles when radius does not differ a lot, but when i have small circles inside a big ones detection does not work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4zoj.jpg)
so, i want to check it from bigger circle (i render spheres, but for collision i use circles, so it is 2-dimensional model). I use index of nearest node and check if distance between current point and closest is less than radius of current (actuallt distance+radius of nearest), and if it is-count few frames, and delete nearest points, but i can't find a way do store information of how long point is inside of a circle, thus points are'not deleted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B9dX.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2DmT.png)

i tried to use index of nearest point as selection for storing attribute and even just as selection for delete geometry nodes, but it does not seem to work.